Is singularity enviorment perserved for Python's subprocess?
I am working on a Python program and I wish to use Python's subprocess's run/Popen functions. I am working on a singularity environment and I found the following post which asks somewhat of a similar question but was left unanswered. I am running the Python from from a singularity environment, is it preserved for the subprocesses?
